# DOCUMENT ROOT variable on PHP-IIS

Tags: php, iis, server-variables

Does the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` variable exist on IIS running PHP? Earlier I thought this variable is Apache specific and on IIS, you have to emulate it by string manipulation of `SCRIPT_NAME` and `SCRIPT_FILENAME` variables but I now see this variable on my PHP installation on IIS. Is it safe to assume that this variable will always be available on IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it safe to assume doc root is always available in IIS?  No...

$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not always available on IIS.. it has to be set in the config file...

If it is configured on your server you 'could' use it...   Just make sure your config file doesn't change - otherwise you will break your scripts...

Comment: config file = php.ini or something else?

Comment: i know in php.ini you can set doc_root (its under the path section) ...  But that sets the global doc_root...

Comment: Just did a google search:  http://forums.iis.net/p/1154314/1932457.aspx   Is an overview of some of the problems with doc_root and multiple sites...  Towards the bottom it references a few links to read up on...  If you only have one site its not an issue...

Comment: 2 out of 3 IIS servers display the `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`. 1 out of these 2 show `$_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` as well. So yes, seems like its not _always_ available.

Comment: What does it mean that this variable is not always present on IIS? What does it depend on? I experienced similar problems when running some "cron" tasks via Task Scheduler, `php-cgi.exe` - but when just simply browsing the websites via a regular browser, I found that `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` *DOES* exist (at least as in many cases as I tried). Another interesting phenomenon: I'm using Xdebug, because it dumps the variables in an easy to follow, colored format, but when hitting F5 multiple times, the Xdebug coloring sometimes doesn't appear to work - kind of like it wasn't loaded at all.Why?

Comment: I don't know why it didn't come into my mind earlier, but obviously, these variables get set via the web server, so variables with these indexes (like `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`, `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`, etc.) won't exist when running a PHP-file "locally" via php-cgi.exe (e.g. via console). If someone needs these variables to be set, and has to run "cron"-files via Task Scheduler, than as a possible solution, one could write a batch script to call all the cron tasks via cURL: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html#Win64MinGW64

Comment: one example for the usage of this (via e.g. Task Scheduler, `php-cgi.exe`) on Windows with redirecting stdout to NUL: `curl example.com/cron.php>NUL`

Answer (score 1):

IIS doesn't always set $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

How do you set it in a configuration file, so the rest of your code works like on Apache servers?

Output $_SERVER to see what IS given that you might be able to use:

```
echo "<br>_SERVER:<br><pre>";
print_r($_SERVER);
echo "</pre><br><br>_ENV:<br><pre>";
print_r($_ENV);
echo "</pre><br><br>";
```

In this case, the SCRIPT_FILENAME and SCRIPT_NAME are set.

Modify the code below to use what is given to get DOCUMENT_ROOT:

```
if (!isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']) || $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] === '') {
    $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] = substr($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], 0, -strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']));
    putenv('DOCUMENT_ROOT='.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
}
```

Now you can use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] normally:

```
$docroot = getenv("DOCUMENT_ROOT"); 
include_once "$docroot/folder/yourfile.php";
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply referencing my web root, and setting it as one of my own variables.

```
<?php
echo getcwd();
chdir('/');
echo getcwd();
chdir('/example-web-server');
echo getcwd();
?>
```

The following code gets the current working directory of PHP, which will be the directory containing the file you're running this on.  `chdir('/')` goes to the root of wherever PHP can operate, in my case `C:\`.  My example web server's web root is at `C:\example-web-server`, so you can reference it in PHP like this:
`/example-web-server`.

Once you've got the path for PHP, you could set it as a variable and call it.  I'll use an example of an `include()` of `C:\example-web-server\testing\index.php`:

```
<?php
$webroot = "/example-web-server";
include("{$webroot}/testing/index.php");
?>
```

I know this is an old thread, but I can't be the only one needing a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on top of index.php:

```
if(!isset($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]))
{
    $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]=getcwd();
}
```